# How to do splash in flutter , i just wanted a background image only for splash screen

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, splash-screen, flutter-native-view

i just wanted to display a splash in flutter , but when i try to run the splash screen the default splash screen of flutter always comes first , how to disable the default splash in flutter , if i can't disable it then what's other solution, i need to display only backgroundImage in my splash screen how to do that in flutter , i have used flutter_native_splash package but it didn't work

i need to display only backgroundImage in my splash screen how to do that in flutter , i have used flutter_native_splash package but it didn't work

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: @Cabdirashiid for android & ios

Comment: @Naruto for that you need to edit code in android  & Ios folder
 for android you need edit launch_background.xml & styles.xml file

Comment: I created a tutorial for Flutter Splash Screen without using any libraries and one with libraries i.e. Flutter Native Splash, they will definitely help you.

Without any Library:  https://youtu.be/MCosWsD5yKc
With Flutter Native Splash: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GV19Hawgpeg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the For AndroidManifest.xml file:

You can locate it in the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file in your Flutter project.

Then just remove or comment out the following lines inside the  tag:
xml

```
> <meta-data
>     android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
>     android:value="true" />
```

For iOS (modify the Info.plist file):

You can locate the ios/Runner/Info.plist file in your Flutter project.
Remove or comment out the following key-value pair:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
```